# Test and publicly share PostGIS queries in a free online environment

Tags: postgis

Is there a way to test and publicly share PostGIS queries in a free online environment?

Similar to what we can do for Oracle queries in environments like these, but for PostGIS:

- [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=57a8174f26f99dabe37392544c997381)  (includes Oracle Spatial)
- [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000) (includes Oracle Spatial)
- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)
- [RexTester](https://rextester.com/) (not free for Oracle)
- Others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes, in db<>fiddle:  [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b438a93e7d395704927d970c37e70189)

> [PostGIS extension available in postgresql](https://topanswers.xyz/fiddle?q=2048)
>
> ...Added PostGIS to v13 and will add to v14 when I rebuild it
> with Rocky.
>
> ```
> select postgis_version()
>
> postgis_version
> ------------------------------------
> 3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
> ```
>
> [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b438a93e7d395704927d970c37e70189)